# PHP Save Record Error Message

Tags: php, mysql

I wonder whether someone could help me please.

I'm trying to put together an administration form where members records can be amended.

The code that I've put together is below and I can successfully retrieve the records from a mySQL database, receiving the appropriate messsage if there are no records with the email address provided.

```
<?php 
mysql_connect ("host","user","password") or die (mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db ("database"); 

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {  
   if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
      $searchemailaddress = $_POST['searchemailaddress']; 
      $sql = mysql_query("select * from userdetails where emailaddress like '$searchemailaddress'"); 
     if (mysql_num_rows($sql) == 0)
        $msg = 'There are no member records set up with this email address, please try again!'; 
     }
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
        $emailaddress = $row['emailaddress'];
        $forename = $row['forename']; 
        $surname = $row['surname']; 
        $subscriptionexpiration = $row['subscriptionexpiration']; 
     }
   } 
   if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
      $emailaddress = $_POST['emailaddress']; 
      $forename = $_POST['forename']; 
      $surname = $_POST['surname'];
      $subscriptionexpiration = $_POST['subscriptionexpiration']; 
      $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE `userdetails` SET `emailaddress` = '$emailaddress', `forename` = '$forename',`surname` = '$surname',`subscriptionexpiration` = '$subscriptionexpiration' LIMIT 1");
      $msg = 'This members records have been successfully updated!'; 
  }
?>
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Search the Database</title> 
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.style1 {font-family: Calibri
}
.style9 {   font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 24px;
    background-color: #78AFC5;
}
.style7 {
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}   
-->
</style>
</head> 
<body> 

  </p>
  <p class="style1">&nbsp;</p>
<div align="center"><span class="style9">Search &amp; Amend User Records </span></div>
<p class="style7"><span class="style10">
  <?php 
if (isset($msg)) // this is special section for 
// outputing message 
{ 
?>
</span>
<p class="style7">
  <?=$msg?>
  <p class="style7"><span class="style10">
  <?php 
} 
?>
  </span>
  <form action="searchandamend.php" method="post">
  <table width="393" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td width="161"><span class="style1">Search:</span></td>
      <td width="207"><span class="style1">
        <input name="searchemailaddress" type="text" id="searchemailaddress" size="25"/>
      </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="style1">Email Address:</span></td>
      <td><span class="style1">
        <input name="emailaddress" type="text"value="<?php echo $emailaddress;?>" size="25"/>
      </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="style1">First Name:</span></td>
      <td><span class="style1">
        <input name="forename" type="text" value="<?php echo $forename;?>" size="20"/>
      </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="style1">Surname:</span></td>
      <td><input name="surname" type="text" value="<?php echo $surname;?>" size="20"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="style1">Subscription Expiry Date:</span> </td>
      <td><input name="subscriptionexpiration" type="text" id="subscriptionexpiration" value="<?php echo $subscriptionexpiration;?>" size="10"/></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <p><br/> 
  <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search Records"> 
  <input name="update" type="submit" value="Update Record"> 
</p>
</form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

However, I'm having problems when I try to change any part of the record. The changes are saved and I receive the correct 'Record updated' message but I also receive this error:
`Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /homepages/2/d333603417/htdocs/development/searchandamend.php on line 14` with line 14 being this line in my code: `while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){` I've been working on this for a while now, and I just can't seem to work out what the problem is.

I just wondered whether someone could perhaps take a look at this please and let me know where I've gone wrong.

Many thanks

Comment: It seems like `$_POST['search']` is set even when you perform a update.

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string()` the variables you include in an SQL query string. You have a *huge* security hole here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All, sincere thanks for taking the time to reply to my post.

After looking at this a little more, and taking into account what you all said, I came up with the following which works fine.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')  
{  
    if (isset($_POST["search"]))  
    {  
$searchemailaddress = $_POST['searchemailaddress'];
$result = mysql_query("select * from userdetails where emailaddress like '$searchemailaddress'");
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
$msg = 'There are no member records with the email address you have provided, please try again!'; 
else
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
$emailaddress = $row['emailaddress'];
$forename = $row['forename']; 
$surname = $row['surname']; 
$subscriptionexpiration = $row['subscriptionexpiration']; 
$msg = 'Record retrieved!';
}
}

if (isset($_POST["update"]))  
    {  
$emailaddress = $_POST['emailaddress']; 
$forename = $_POST['forename']; 
$surname = $_POST['surname']; 
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE `userdetails` SET `emailaddress` = '$emailaddress', `forename` = '$forename',`surname` = '$surname', `subscriptionexpiration` = '$subscriptionexpiration' LIMIT 1");
$msg = 'This members record has been successfully updated!';
}
}
```

Kind regards

Comment: @IRHM- Try indenting your code, it will make it much easier to read. If this is the correct solution, you should accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (mysql_num_rows($sql) == 0)
```

You are not opening a bracket!

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {  
   if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
      $searchemailaddress = $_POST['searchemailaddress']; 
      $sql = mysql_query("select * from userdetails where emailaddress like '$searchemailaddress'"); 
      if (mysql_num_rows($sql) == 0)
          $msg = 'There are no member records set up with this email address, please try     again!'; 
      }
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
       $emailaddress = $row['emailaddress'];
       $forename = $row['forename']; 
       $surname = $row['surname']; 
       $subscriptionexpiration = $row['subscriptionexpiration']; 
    }
}
```

}
This makes the `isset($_POST['search'])` if block to close before the `while`.

You probably want something like this:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {  
    if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
        $searchemailaddress = $_POST['searchemailaddress']; 
        $sql = mysql_query("select * from userdetails where emailaddress like '$searchemailaddress'"); 
        if (mysql_num_rows($sql) == 0) {
            $msg = 'There are no member records set up with this email address, please try     again!'; 
        }
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) { 
            $emailaddress = $row['emailaddress'];
            $forename = $row['forename']; 
            $surname = $row['surname']; 
            $subscriptionexpiration = $row['subscriptionexpiration']; 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the connection is not being successfully created and you are trying to fetch and array from the returned boolean?